# Python regex remove and replace characters

Tags: python, regex

I need to use `python` to remove the `%22` from the `NAME` below and replace it with a blank space.

How would that be done?

```
NAME = 'best%22buy'
```

Comment: If this is a percent-encoded value from a URL, `%22` is a `"`, not a space.

Answer (score 2):

Use string replace not a regular expression.

```
NAME = NAME.replace("%22", ' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

`NAME='best%22buy'.replace('%22',' ')`

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, if you **really** want to use regex for this, I'd do:

```
 re.sub(r'\%22', '', 'best%22buy')
```

Otherwise, I'd do what everyone else is saying and do a find-replace:

```
'best%22buy'.replace('%22', '')
```

The second option is better in my opinion, *unless* you have a ton of other regex in the same area and you want to keep everything consistent.  Or if you are going *crazy* with regex... like you re looping through a ton of find/replace parameters.